# Is there a simple way to print out special characters from a file to console in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a problem where I am attempting to add appropriate articles to the beginning of French country names. That part wasn't an issue but trying to print it out hasn't worked so well. There are special characters in the file and while it seems to read them just fine it won't print them out just fine. I am using visual studios and here are examples of words from the text file named "FrenchCountriesUnfinished.txt" that I am trying to print out

l'Algérie,
la Norvège,
la Zélande,
la Suède,
le Zaïre

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("FrenchCountriesUnfinished.txt");
    string str;

    while (getline(file, str)) {

        cout << str << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the character encoding of that file?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the actual problem in action. Note that handling Unicode characters (not "special" characters) in file I/O is a bit easier (especially if you let C++ streams+facets do the hard work for you) than handling Unicode in the Windows console (which can be tricky - there are *numerous* questions on StackOverflow on that very topic).

Comment: After reading some articles to try to understand what you mean, I think it may be Unix (LF) or ANSI. If that doesn't make sense that means idk what I'm searching for or what that means lol

Comment: @CashtonHolbert: If the file is a (terrible) ASCII superset like latin-1 or cp1252, and your terminal is (the only good ASCII superset) UTF-8, the bytes will be incompatible. Welcome to the "wonderful" world of text encodings!

Comment: Well I can make my own file for this, and since that is the case, what your saying is that I can change the file text encoding or something to align with the terminal text encoding for visual studios? @ShadowRanger

Comment: The problem is that the Windows console doesn't use UTF-8 so special characters don't print right - if you redirect the output to a file it will work fine.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391252/how-to-print-latin-characters-to-the-c-console-properly-on-windows  one answer suggests `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` would work.

Comment: @CashtonHolbert: Yes, though that depends heavily on the terminal. `cmd.exe` defaults to [cp437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) last I checked, and that's a encoding basically no file is encoded in (it's great for line drawing and icons; not so much for expanding the text options). There are C++ libraries (as Remy Lebeau mentioned) and Windows APIs that can convert between encodings, which is likely the only "good" solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll still see what I can do to print it out in console but that sounds wayyyy more sensible @JerryJeremiah

Comment: I definitely think this looks like it would work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391252/how-to-print-latin-characters-to-the-c-console-properly-on-windows/13393518#13393518

Comment: UTF-8 support in console depend on Windows version and must be set somehow. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235341/is-there-a-simple-way-to-print-out-special-characters-from-a-file-to-console-in.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app